# security tools for kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openshift

Is there any other alternative of `kube-bench` for ocp4.3 regarding cis benchmark or any replacement of `kube-bench` for using cis benchmark. I need a security tool that can check all the vulnerabilities in kubernetes cluster not only image scanning and configuration.

Comment: There's [kube-hunter](https://github.com/aquasecurity/kube-hunter) and [kube-scan](https://github.com/octarinesec/kube-scan). But, to my knowledge, they are not focused on implementing CIS benchmark.

Answer (score 1):

[Inspec](https://github.com/inspec/inspec) is recommended from Docker for running [CIS Kubernetes benchmark](https://github.com/dev-sec/cis-kubernetes-benchmark).

> Note: The above `Inspec` implementation provides - the CIS Kubernetes 1.5.0 Benchmark.

Also, [kubeaudit](https://github.com/Shopify/kubeaudit) might be of use - but I don't see specific CIS benchmark extension.

Comment: Worth noting that CIS benchmark version is *very* old (although so is the version of Openshift OP is looking at!) and targets kubeadm rather than OpenShift.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding security check, take a look at these tools:

[Clair](https://coreos.com/clair/docs/latest/) Clair is an open source project for the static analysis of vulnerabilities in the containers.

[Aqua](https://www.aquasec.com/) a container security platform

[k8guard](https://k8guard.github.io/) can check for common problems with your cluster and either take corrective action or just send you a notification about them.

[Copper](https://copper.sh/) is a tool for checking your Kubernetes manifests before deploying them

Hope to be useful for you

Answer (score 0):

CIS benchmark scanning can be a tricky business as it's important to make sure the tool implements the benchmark that corresponds to both the distribution and version that you're using (Well as close as possible as there aren't CIS benchmark versions for every distribution or version :) )

You might struggle to get a scanner specifically for that version (OpenShift 4.3) as that's out of support, so even an up to date OpenShift scanner is likely to have some incorrect results.

There are tools that generically do Kubernetes mis-configuration scanning that fits in with CIS, although I don't believe they specifically have a profile for Openshift 4.3.

- [Trivy](https://aquasecurity.github.io/trivy/v0.28.1/docs/kubernetes/cli/scanning/)
- [kubescape](https://github.com/kubescape/kubescape)

Some other tooling you can explore for container/k8s security [here](https://www.container-security.site/general_information/tools_list.html)